# CSS animation working everywhere but not in IE and edge?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-animations, microsoft-edge

All is in the title, I cannot figure out why my animation is working everywhere but not in IE and edge. Where am I missing something ?

Here are the keyframes of my animation and the [JS fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/7AuQM/23/) associated

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#toggle').hide();
});

$('#toggler').click(function () {
  $("#toggle").delay(800).velocity("slideDown", {
    duration: 1200
  });

  $("#footer").delay(800).velocity("scroll", {
    duration: 1200
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
#content1 {
  width:100%;
  height:800px;
  background-color:grey;
  position:relative;
}
#toggler {
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
  bottom:10px;
  margin-left: auto; 
  margin-right: auto; 
  width: 100px;
  height:50px;
}
#footer {
  background-color:black;
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
}
.slide-up {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  width:100%;
}
.animate {  
  animation: super-zgeger-mob 5s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  z-index: 9999;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-animation: super-zgeger-mob linear 5s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -moz-animation: super-zgeger-mob linear 5s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -o-animation: super-zgeger-mob linear 5s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  -ms-animation: super-zgeger-mob linear 5s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes super-zgeger-mob {
  0% {
    transform: translate(-90%, 0%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    transform: translate(-90%, 0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(-5%, 0%) rotate(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(150%, 0%);
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes super-zgeger-mob {
  0% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-90%, 0%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-90%, 0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    -moz-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
  75% {
    -moz-transform: translate(-5%, 0%) rotate(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform: translate(150%, 0%);
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes super-zgeger-mob {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-90%, 0%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-90%, 0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
  75% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-5%, 0%) rotate(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(150%, 0%);
  }
}
@-o-keyframes super-zgeger-mob {
  0% {
    -o-transform: translate(-90%, 0%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    -o-transform: translate(-90%, 0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    -o-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
  75% {
    -o-transform: translate(-5%, 0%) rotate(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform: translate(150%, 0%);
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes super-zgeger-mob {
  0% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-90%, 0%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  15% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-90%, 0%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    -ms-transform: translate(0%, 0%);
  }
  75% {
    -ms-transform: translate(-5%, 0%) rotate(10deg);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform: translate(150%, 0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id=content1>
    <button id="toggler">
    push me
    </button>
</div>
<div id="toggle">
  <div id="animation" style="position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;">
    <img src="http://image.gilawhost.com/16/11/09/jzjhk7o0.png" class="slide-up"/>
    <img id="rolling" src="http://image.gilawhost.com/16/11/09/6d7tsk5k.png" class="slide-up animate" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; z-index: 99;" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id=footer> 
</div>
```

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/7AuQM/24/ works for me in IE11. (Removed vendor prefixes)

Comment: FYI: You should always write the vendor-prefixed versions first, and have the unprefixed one come last.

Comment: @Kyle that is weird as this fiddle does not work in my IE 11 or my edge browser neither.

Comment: @CBroe thanks for the tips but why ?

Comment: @Geniom as the browser will go through all the vendor prefixed ones until it finds its own, ignoring the others. If it doesn't need a vendor prefix, it will use the standard syntax. Btw: Vendor prefixes are no longer needed for latest browsers with keyframe animations.

Comment: `-ms-` prefix isn't needed for keyframes, since IE9 doesn't understand them at all and IE10+ understands them unprefixed. `-moz-` prefix isn't needed, too, as Firefox supports the unprefixed syntax since version 16 (released 4 years ago!). `-o-` prefix is also useless here because both Opera 12.1 and current Chrome-based Opera support unprefixed syntax, and Opera Mini doesn't support animations by its nature. Only `-webkit-` prefix can be helpful for some old mobile browsers, but animations may be too heavy for the old hardware they work on, so using unprefixed syntax only may be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, Using positioning on .animate (left:-90% to desired position) over translate() property will work for you.
translate partially supported by IE 11 only and in opera its also wont work properly.
http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d.